# Как говорить правильно: "два штуки" или "две штуки"?

Tags: пунктуация, орфоэпия

Подскажите правильное употребление слова "штука". Можно ли говорить "два штуки"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: две штуки, так как штука - ж.род.

В русском языке значение рода выражают только некоторые числительные:  два/две,  оба/обе  и полтора/полторы, причем существуют не три, а две формы для выражения рода:  для м.р. и ср. р. и для ж. р..